# Compare predictive strength of a linear model with logistic model?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, linear

I have a 6 independent variables and 2 target variables: One target is continuous, the other is binary. I want to know whether the 6 independents are better at predicting the continuous variable or the binary variable.

I've looked at comparing r^2 with a pseudo r^2 for logistic regression, but I know pseudo r^2 is not an ideal measurement here. Is there a better option that would allow me to compare the predictive strengths of these?

I'm using R, so any direction on the appropriate package & method to use there would be very much appreciated.

Edit 1: For individual predictors, I tried a point-biserial correlation for the binary target. I also tried pearson's correlation for the binary target (1 & 0). Pearson's & Point-Biserial produced the exact same r^2 value, only the Point-Biserial was negative. I'm not sure why...?

Edit 2: Should I be looking at some measure of "fit"? If so, which would be comparable across both models?

Comment: Are the two outcome variables related or are they measuring different things?

Comment: They are related. I'm measuring success of individuals based on prior knowledge (the independent variable) and have two measures of success that are related, but not identical. I've read a bit that linear regression on a binary 1/0 variable can be a valid approach (aparantly it's common in economic analysis), and on that basis there is a clear "winner" in terms of how well one of the dependents can be predicted, but I'd be more comfortable if I could show that "winner" using the more traditional logistic approach for my binary dependent.

Comment: Estimating a linear probability model (with OLS) would have been my suggestion. Comparing $R^2$ is good, because it's relative to the best intercept-only model of that outcome, but the problem with logit v ols is that different error metrics are optimised and the magnitude of how much the best intercept model is improved by the model (measured by $R^2$ and pseudo $R^2$ ) neednt be comparable. What you could do is manually calculate $R^2$  (using mean squared error) with the predictions of the logit model. Or you estimate a model with the logit link using non-linear least squares